# Is there a shortcut for unix `cp` to copy a file to the current directory with the same filename?

Tags: linux, cp

I'm hoping there's a shorter way of copying a file from a given directory to the current working directory than typing `cp /path/to/file.txt file.txt`

I tend to use this command a lot, and reiterating the file name seems... well... redundant.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"." refers to the current directory, so

```
cp /path/to/file .
```

will do what you want.

Comment: and don't forget the ~.  It gives the users home directory. Quite convenient.

Comment: @Alan Shutko,  D'oh!  I'm very much used to using `..` to go up a level in the directory tree, but I never even thought about what the `.` could possibly mean!  @Matt H, Yes, I often use `~/`, but it's good to know that `~.` also works!  Thank you both!